# 2 minipages side by side don't respect the width of an article

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, minipage, lncs

In one of my `.tex` file, I have the following code which puts 2 `minipage`s side by side, the whole width cover two minipages:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.125in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in}

% \documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}

\input{fonts.tex}
\input{macros.tex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}%
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
  \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
      \hspace*{0em}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.6]
          \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,0) rectangle (10,2);
          \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,5) rectangle (6,12);
          \filldraw[fill=white!20] (6,5) rectangle (10,12);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
  \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
      \raisebox{0em}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.6]
          \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,0) rectangle (6,7);
          \filldraw[fill=white!20] (8,0) rectangle (12,7);
          \filldraw[fill=white!20] (2,-5) rectangle (12,-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}\\
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

In a new `.tex` file, I need to use `\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}`, so I remove all the `\setlength`, with the same code, the `minipage`s are a little bit too large, and do not respect the border on the right...

Does anyone know which parameter I need to change so that the 2 `minipage`s respect the width of the article?

**Edit1:** Sorry guys, you could finally try the code above and switch between `article` and `llncs`. You will see that for `llncs`, the minipages exceed a little bit the border on the right... Could we amend that?

Comment: Please consider expanding your code into a compilable MWE.

Comment: I don't see any overflow.

Comment: I have added more packages that I use, maybe they raise the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `tikzpicture` is too big for the `minipage`.  I added `\usepackage{showframe}` so that we can see where the margins are.

As you can see from the two minipages of text, things fit fine. Only with the `tikzpicture` do you have the overflow. Hence you need to reduce the size of your picture by adjusting the scale.

[image]

### Notes:

- Using `\showthe\linewidth`, we see that the `\linewidth=451.6875pt` for the `article` class, and `\linewidth=347.12354pt` with the `llncs` class.  This reduction in the width is what is causing the pictures to no longer fit within the `minipage` and flow into the margin.
- The `geometry` package changes the `\linewidth` and hence the problem does not show up if you use `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`.

### Code:

```
%\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.125in}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in}

\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Text}{%
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

\begin{document}
%\showthe\linewidth
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \Text
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \Text
\end{minipage}


\bigskip\noindent
\Text

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
  \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
      \hspace*{0em}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.6]
          \filldraw[fill=red!20] (2,0) rectangle (10,2);
          \filldraw[fill=blue!20] (2,5) rectangle (6,12);
          \filldraw[fill=green!20] (6,5) rectangle (10,12);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
  \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
      \raisebox{0em}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.6]
          \filldraw[fill=brown!20] (2,0) rectangle (6,7);
          \filldraw[fill=orange!20] (8,0) rectangle (12,7);
          \filldraw[fill=violet!20] (2,-5) rectangle (12,-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}%

\noindent\Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I have got the same image as you after adding `showframe`, with or without `fonts.tex` and `macros.tex`. However, without `showframe`, the `minipage` still exceeds the right border, with or without the tex files... By the way, I use `llncs` instead of `llncs2e/llncs`...

Comment: Ok, have updated the answer - your pictures were too big.  The `llncs2e/llncs` was just an artifact of where I downloaded the class to. And `\usepacakge{showframe}` seems to show the problem without changing the size as the `geometry` package was doing.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen `showframe`. Thanks!