# mdframed and supertabular disagreeing on positioning (supertabular bug?)

Tags: positioning, mdframed, supertabular

Finding that a certain table in my document had to span several pages, and that `longtable` [doesn't fit the bill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46205) because I have to change the running header mid-table, I turned to `supertabular`.

To [get the vertical spacing right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46294) I use `booktabs`.

Since *that* broke the vertical lines surrounding the table, I thought about working around that by wrapping the whole table in `mdframed`.

So far about the history why anyone would want to wrap a `supertabular` with `mdframed` in the first place. ;-)

Now to the issue at hand: It appears that the two packages disagree on positioning by a couple of pt...?

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt]
\begin{supertabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
\hline
Foo & Bar\\
\hline
\end{supertabular*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Somewhat unexpected result:

[image]

Erm... huh?

**EDIT:** Further testing showed that it is supertabular's hline being pushed to the right (out of the text area), not mdframed pushed to the left. Testing also showed this to be specific to supertabular, as neither longtable, tabularx or tabular* displayed similar behaviour. Bug report mailed to supertabular maintainer, CC mdframed maintainer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an outdated TeX-distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some older libraries.

Using your code with TeXLive (updated today) and adding `\usepacakge{showframe}` I get:

[image]

Without the `showframe` package I get;

[image]

## Notes:

- Am using `showframe` package as opposed to `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` as the latter changes the page width as I recently discovered while attempting to solve [2 minipages side by side don't respect the width of an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46170/2-minipages-side-by-side-dont-respect-the-width-of-an-article/46183#46183).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt]
    \begin{supertabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
        \hline
        Foo & Bar\\
        \hline
    \end{supertabular*}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, a recent update seems to have solved the issue. Sorry for the fuzz.